# Cloudkit error in fetching user record ID

Tags: swift, record, cloudkit

I'm creating an app that uses cloudkit and I'm getting an error that I don't understand
this is my code:

```
CKContainer *defaultContainer =[CKContainer defaultContainer];
CKDatabase *publicDB = [defaultContainer publicCloudDatabase];
[defaultContainer fetchUserRecordIDWithCompletionHandler:^(CKRecordID *recordID, NSError *error) {
    if(error){
        NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"1 %@", error.description]);}
    else{
        [publicDB fetchRecordWithID:recordID completionHandler:^(CKRecord *record, NSError *error) {
            if(error){
                NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"2 %@", error.description]);}
            else{
                record[@"name"]=name.text;
                record[@"phone"]=phone.text;
                record[@"building"]=building.text;
                record[@"apartment"]=apartment.text;
                [publicDB saveRecord:record completionHandler:^(CKRecord *record, NSError *error) {
                    if(error){
                         NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"3 %@", error.description]);}
                    else{
                         NSLog(@"success");}}];}}];}}];
```

and this is the error Im getting:

2014-07-21 02:20:01.569 grocer[6312:415125] 1 X-MMe-Client-Info/X-Apple-Client-Info header did not meet the minimum build version, rejecting request

Comment: Try error.localizedDescription in NSLog

Comment: Thanks @Shmidt
I did it already and edited my post
can you please check it again

Comment: What Xcode version so you use? 6 beta 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed they came out with beta 4 of XCode - I have beta 3 and am getting the same error - I'm downloading the new one now to see if that fixes the error.

Comment: I can confirm that updating to the latest version fixed the problem with the "X-MMe-Client-Info/X-Apple-Client-Info header did not meet the minimum build version, rejecting request" error.

Answer (score 0):

Your iOS deployment target should be iOS 7 or later and your base SDK should be 8